Jodit-editor and pasting rtf from powerpoint
When pasting from powerpoint to jodit editor some spaces get removed and some not, there isn't some rule.
In the jodit config object i pass
const config  = useMemo(() => ({{
askBeforePasteHTML: false,
askBeforePasteFromWord: false,
defaultActionOnPaste: 'insert_as_html',

}), [someVar]);

This does paste html tags inside, but even text in the same line in some powerpoint slide gets its spaces removed for some resaon.
Also tried events like beforePaste as noted in the JODIT docs, i see the spaces in the content when debugging, then pastes again with no spaces.
You can try playing with it here:
JODIT DEMO
then change in src/components/jodit/JoditEditor.jsx
this line:
defaultActionOnPaste: 'insert_clear_html',

into:
defaultActionOnPaste: 'insert_as_html',

Then copy paste some formatted text in powerpoint
Is there any idea how to tackle it?
